# Cannot print correctly at the same time an ArrayList and a form in HTML using Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I am facing problem trying print at the same time a form and array in the same HTML.

Here is my usuario class:

```
public class usuario {

    private String user_id;
    private String createdAt;
    private String address;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String birthday;
    private String email;
    private String user_idp;
    private ArrayList pedido;
    private String phoneNunmber;
    private Integer edad;
    public String nombre;
    private String confirmationCode;
    private String promotions;

    public String ciudad;

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getPromotions() {
        return promotions;
    }

    public void setPromotions(String promotions) {
        this.promotions = promotions;
    }

    public String getConfirmationCode() {
        return confirmationCode;
    }

    public void setConfirmationCode(String confirmationCode) {
        this.confirmationCode = confirmationCode;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Integer getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getPhoneNunmber() {
        return phoneNunmber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNunmber(String phoneNunmber) {
        this.phoneNunmber = phoneNunmber;
    }

    public String getUser_idp() {
        return user_idp;
    }

    public void setUser_idp(String user_idp) {
        this.user_idp = user_idp;
    }

    public ArrayList getPedido() {
        return pedido;
    }

    public void setPedido(ArrayList pedido) {
        this.pedido = pedido;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }



}
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @GetMapping("/allusers")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) throws ParseException{
        tablausuario tu = new tablausuario();
        ArrayList<usuario> user = tu.listausuarios();
        Collections.sort(user, (o1, o2) -> o2.getCreatedAt().compareTo(o1.getCreatedAt())); //tabla ordenada
        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);        
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/allusers")
    public String greetingSubmit(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute usuario users) {
        String ciudad = request.getParameter("ciudad");
        tablausuariofilterbycity tufc = new tablausuariofilterbycity();
        ArrayList<usuario> userbycity = tufc.listausuariosfiltradosporciudad(ciudad);
        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", userbycity);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

And here is my HTML "greeting"

```
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Listado de usuarios </h2> 
            <p th:text=" ${TodosLosUsuarios.size()} "></p>    
            <div id="capa"> </div> 
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/allusers}" th:object="${TodosLosUsuarios}" method="post">
                <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{ciudad}" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
            </form>

            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Buscar por ciudad..">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Día creado</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>
                        <th>Confirmado</th>
                        <th>Promocion</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody  th:each="usuariosTotales: ${TodosLosUsuarios}" >
                    <tr>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getNombre()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getEmail()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getPhoneNunmber()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getCreatedAt()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getEdad()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getConfirmationCode()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getPromotions()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getAddress()} " ></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


    </div>
```

I am sure that the problem is in the form:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/allusers}" th:object="${TodosLosUsuarios}" method="post">
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{ciudad}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

If instead of "user" I use "new usuario"

```
        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);
```

I use

```
        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", new usuario());
```

the form works but I am not able to read the ArrayList, and I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "greeting" - line 10, col 40)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "greeting" - line 10, col 40)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ciudad' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'ciudad' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 63 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stack clearly points out where the problem is:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "greeting" - line 10, col 40)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ciudad' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'ciudad' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

You are trying to use one model attribute for two actual elements: for the list of users and for the form. If you are passing the list of the users with parameter named "TodosLosUsuarios" to the model, you cannot use the same for the form, which is going to create and pass a single object (user) only.

Try to add another attribute to your model:

```
model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);        
model.addAttribute("newUser", new usuario());
```

And then in your `greeting` template, replace object's name to "newUser":

```
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/allusers}" th:object="${newUser}" method="post">
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{ciudad}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

So your controller should look like this:

```
    @Controller
    public class GreetingController {


        @GetMapping("/allusers")
        public String greetingForm(Model model) throws ParseException{
            tablausuario tu = new tablausuario();
            ArrayList<usuario> user = tu.listausuarios();
            Collections.sort(user, (o1, o2) -> o2.getCreatedAt().compareTo(o1.getCreatedAt())); //tabla ordenada
            model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);
            model.addAttribute("newUser", new usuario());        
            return "greeting";
        }

        @PostMapping("/allusers")
        public String greetingSubmit(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute usuario newUser) {
            String ciudad = request.getParameter("ciudad");
            tablausuariofilterbycity tufc = new tablausuariofilterbycity();
            ArrayList<usuario> userbycity = tufc.listausuariosfiltradosporciudad(ciudad);
            model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", userbycity);
            return "result";
        }

    }
```